# PHP: set_error_handler and visibily

Tags: php, error-handling, visibility

In my class constructor, I have the following:

```
set_error_handler(array(
    $this,
    '_custom_error_handler'
));
```

In the same class, I have the following method defined:

```
protected function _custom_error_handler($error_number, $error_string, $error_file, $error_line)
```

When something in my code runs into an error, I get the following warning:

> **Warning:** Invalid callback ... _custom_error_handler, cannot access protected method

Why can't this class (or its children?) access this protected method? Shouldn't a protected method be accessible???

Comment: Callbacks do allow access to protected methods but wherever the PHP core launches your callback does not belong to the class. Please note the difference with calling `call_user_func()` yourself.

Comment: You should read up on the PHP coding standards, specifically [PSR-2 method names](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#methods). It says: *Method names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.*

Answer (score 3):

A protected method is only accessible from inside the class, or subclasses.

In this case set_error_handler is calling a method, and set_error_handler is *outside* your class. Therefore it must be public.

Comment: I don't find the "set_error_handler is outside your class" part very clear—since it's using `$this` without errors it's clear that it's inside the class. I presume you mean the context from which the callback function is eventually called.